# Use RegEx to Search for Term and Extract Characters Before and After It

Tags: regex

I'm struggling to find the correct syntax to use that will parse a page for a term and then output any 100 characters (HTML included) before the term + the term + any 100 characters after the term.

I'm using Screaming Frog to search my website and I need to see the context for each occurrence of the term.

So I would want my output to look something like:

```
...i>two</li></ul><h4>title</h4>Help me this is my TERM and i want to view things. Can you se...
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To match up to 100 chars before and after a term:

```
.{0,100}TERM.{0,100}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! However, it's only outputing the first 100 characters and not the last 100. What modification can I make?